# Как создать папку с настройками?

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня тут вопросик появился. Ни как не могу найти в интернете! Как сделать так, что бы одно поле ввода указывало имя папки, а другое поле ввода указывало на путь его создания! И после введённых данных, нажимать на кнопку .Создать. И всё работало. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А создавать одно поле и считывать из него значение вы уже умеете?

Comment: Вам поможет `SaveFileDialog`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    
    namespace Folder
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
    
            private void createBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string path = textBox1.Text;
                string folderName = textBox2.Text;
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path + "\\" + folderName);
            }
        }

}
```

Путь в таком виде:

```
D:\blsbls\blabla
```

Comment: Показывает ошибку System.ArgumentException: "Путь содержит недопустимые знаки."

Comment: Покажите как Вы путь прописываете?

Comment: я ввожу путь папки в текстовое поле , вот пример: C:\Users\user\Documents\Test

Comment: Попробуйте вот так написать
Directory.CreateDirectory(@path + "\\" + folderName);
 Либо вы в названии папки какой-то символ пишите, типа знака вопроса или слеша

Comment: только что проверил! Не работает( такая же ошибка

Comment: Это 100% рабочий код. Какое имя папки Вы пишете? Может быть Вы пишете имя файла, а не папки? Если Вам нужно создать файл, то код надо слегка изменить.

Comment: string path = textBox1.Text;
            string folderName = textBox2.Text;
            Directory.CreateDirectory(@path + "\\" + folderName); это код который вы считаете правильным!  Но VisualStruio жалуется(

Comment: Скажите, что Вы пишите в textbox2? Просто у меня всё работает, а Ваша ошибка возникает только тогда, когда я пишу какие-либо запрещенные символы в названии папки.

Comment: Название папки MyCanvas1 ,  Путь C:\Users\user\Documents\Test

Comment: я убрал в названии единицу! и теперь ошибка:  System.NotSupportedException: "Данный формат пути не поддерживается."

Comment: Создайте новый чистый проект с двумя текстбоками и кнопкой, и попробуйте в нём (напишите путь покороче и руками) ошибка из разряда невоспроизводимых, я не могу вызвать её у себя, какие бы значения я не вводил

Comment: попробовал! не работает(

Comment: Дадите подключиться по teamviewer? Мне уже самому интересно. Напишите в телегу @souloftrue